# What is the meaning of using : near a method/constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack

Suppose to have the following move constructor (StackVec inherits from Vector)

```
template <typename Data>
StackVec<Data>::StackVec(StackVec&& stkV) noexcept : Vector<Data>(std::move(stkV)){
    std::move(index, stkV.index);
}
```

What is the difference if I instead write something like this

```
template <typename Data>
StackVec<Data>::StackVec(StackVec&& stkV) noexcept{
    Vector<Data>(std::move(stkV))
    std::move(index, stkV.index);
}
```

So what : near a method/constructor is used for?

Comment: `std::move(index, stkV.index);` That's just wrong. Google "constructor initializer list c++".

Comment: That code looks wrong from inception. Neither should even compile, so rather than seeking a difference, consider what they have in common: they're both broken. The usage of `std:move` with two arguments should be puking all over your error log at compile time. I hesitate to believe you understand what `std::move` *does*. And the second, assuming a semi-colon  mid-code was somehow excised from your copy/paste, uses default initialization of the base class, then constructs a *temporary* `Vector<Data>(std::move(stkV))` in the body of the ctor, throws it way, and then that broken `std::move`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to construct a member variable with your parameters you should give them in this section. After entering the body of the constructor it is only possible to change/alter them which in most cases is not intended.